# How can I style an ahref element in a span element using CSS?

Tags: css

So in the below html in my wp site I need to make the tel number bigger:

```
<div class="cmsmasters-icon-phone-4">
    <span>
        <span>Call Us Anytime</span>
        <a href="tel:0800-689-0150"><strong> 0800 689 0150</strong></a>
    </span>
```

I've tried adding the below CSS:

```
.cmsmasters-icon-phone-4 span.a {
font-size:20;
}
```

without much luck. I'm still a newbie so any help would be appreciated

Comment: `span.a` selects a `span` element that has the _class_ `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong at `span.a` this is the selector for a `span` with class a (`<span class="a">`)
Change it to `.cmsmasters-icon-phone-4 span a` so a space instead of a `.`

Comment: thanks I've tried .cmsmasters-icon-phone-4 span a {
font-size:20px;
}
but still didn't work ..the text is in the header of the below page - the number didn't seem to change its font size
https://nalogistics.co.uk

Comment: than `strong` probably has a `font-size` defined change it to `.cmsmasters-icon-phone-4 span a strong { font-size: 20rem;}`

Comment: thanks, tried it like this too but still not working :(

Comment: or should I try removing strong and add it to css instead

Comment: Inspect the element in your browser and see if something is overriding it and did you refresh cache??

Comment: you're right it's being overriden by this as in inspect font size is crossed

.header_mid .slogan_wrap .slogan_wrap_text strong {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, Helvetica, 'Nimbus Sans L', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;

is there anyway I can preserve the font for my span a not to be overriden by this?

Comment: You can add `!important` `.cmsmasters-icon-phone-4 span a strong { font-size: 20px !important;}`

Comment: I tried again the important tag as well but still no joy. This time I can't even see it via inspect. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the HTML in your question is correct? And can you send your current css selector

Comment: Yes..as I can easily modify it and the changes are reflected on the website. The CSS selector I've added the !important .cmsmasters-icon-phone-4 span a strong { 
font-size: 20px !important;
} in the custom CSS section of WP

Comment: `.header_mid .slogan_wrap .slogan_wrap_text strong` you said this is the selector that overwrites your css but I don't see the `.slogan_wrap_text` in your html

Comment: I added it via the theme's custom header html feature so it's added automatically after this [link]#header > div.header_mid > div > div > div.slogan_wrap > div > div [link]

Comment: Managed to make it work with this 
.cmsmasters-icon-phone-4 a strong {
font-size: 20px !important;
}